# Key properties of all entity types must be mapped to the same non-nullable columns returned by the storage function

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-function

I've just created a table-valued function as described here http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/table-valued-function-in-entity-framework5.aspx (using EF6) and imported it into my edmx.
After this I also changed the `Returns a collection of` to my entity `MyTable` (which is selected inside the function).

However, I always get the exception

> The key properties of all entity types returned by the function import must be mapped to the same non-nullable columns returned by the storage function.

When I look into the generated complex result-object all properties are `nullable` but in my entity `MyTable` I want to map to they are not.

This is my function (to get all child-relations from a given entity except the entity itself):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetChildren]
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @Id uniqueidentifier
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
    WITH childs  AS
    (
       SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Id = @Id
       UNION ALL
       SELECT MyTable.* FROM MyTable JOIN childs ON MyTable.ParentId = childs.Id
    )

    SELECT * FROM  childs WHERE Id <> @Id
)
```

The function works as expected when running inside sql-server. The edmx-generation also runs through. But, when trying to execute a query with the `DbContext` I got this error (no matter if I call the function-import or not).

Is this an issue with the function itself, EF or is there something other wrong with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ISNULL` for the key columns in your `SELECT` list to force EF to recognize the value as non-nullable:

```
WITH childs  AS
(
   SELECT Id FROM MyTable WHERE Id = @Id
   UNION ALL
   SELECT MyTable.Id FROM MyTable JOIN childs ON MyTable.ParentId = childs.Id
)

SELECT ISNULL(Id, 0) FROM  childs WHERE Id <> @Id
```

You won't be able to do this with `SELECT *`, but you shouldn't do that anyway.

Comment: So do I have to select all columns and those (which are not nullable in my entity) should be sourrounded by the `ISNULL`?

Comment: @KingKerosin, yes that's what you need to do.

Comment: BTW: When only using the second part I get the `Recursive common table expression 'childs' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator.`

Comment: At the end I only had to change the last `SELECT *` in order to make the EDMX understand the types correctly. Thanks!

Comment: @KingKerosin: Updating my post accordingly.